# How to export / create / map Excel table data to a multilevel xml or group with XPath

Tags: excel, xml, dictionary, xpath, export

I have a excel table of this kind:

```
Date        Time
10-11-2020  7:00
10-11-2020  8:00
10-11-2020  9:00
11-11-2020  5:00
11-11-2020  6:00
11-11-2020  9:00
```

that i would like to translate/map to an xml file with a structure such as:

```
<node>
 <date1>
   <time1>
   <time2>
   <time3>
 <date2>
   <time1>
   <time2>
   <time3>
</node>
```

what I am currently getting is:

```
<node>
 <date1>
   <time1>
 <date1>
   <time2>
 <date1>
   <time3>
 <date2>
   <time1>
 <date2>
   <time2>
 <date2>
   <time3>
</node>
```

How can I create such a multilevel structure from excel or alternatively: What would be the Xpath expression to group the date field?

many thanks in advance

Comment: Would it be possible to share what is your current code that is producing the above result?

Comment: i have no code, I am importing a excel file into wordpress with wp all import plugin, which reads the xlsx with xpath. the structure showed in last section is how excel stores the table in its internal xml.

Comment: I don't know if you are familiar with xquery and if it's available to you, but if you do - it can be used to convert the xml you are currently geting to the xml you want.

Comment: unfortunetely not :(